# HAPI complie Exception class file version 55.0 file versions up to 52.0

Tags: hapi

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ca/uhn/hl7v2/HL7Exception has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
以上是我执行main方法时的报错